# Response code when POST fails to complete

Tags: rest

I have a scenario where a client Posts to a resource and if the data in the post is not valid then I want to return back a error saying what caused the failure. I am thinking that a 409 with a response body is appropriate? anyone any thoughts or suggestions on a different response?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

- 400 means the request as such was not understood (e.g. bad syntax)
- 409 means request understood but there is a conflict the client might solve (e.g with PATCH)
- 415 means the submitted media type is not understood by server
- 422 means the data was syntactically correct but semantically wrong

What do you mean by 'not valid'
HTH,

Jan

Comment: Say in the request there is an email address and i validate it before returning a response, if that validation fails i want to return back a message saying that the email address validation has failed accompanied by a suitable response code

Comment: 422 is the closest to your scenario.

Comment: Hmmm 422 is a WebDAV standard code and i don't want to use those?

Comment: It's fine to use 422 it's in the IANA list, it's used by Rails and best of all it's semantically a good fit for what you need.